# Prove that if $d_1=\gcd(a,b), d_2=\gcd(b,c), d_3=\gcd(c,a), D=\gcd(a,b,c)$, and $L=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)$, then $L= \frac{abcD}{d_1 d_2 d_3}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I tried to define: 
$a=d_1x_1$, $b=d_1y_1$;
$b=d_2x_2$, $c=d_2y_2$;
$c=d_3x_3$, $c=d_3y_3$.

then $\operatorname{L.H.S}
=d_1d_2d_3x_1x_2x_3=d_1d_2d_3y_1y_2y_3$ $\implies$ $x_1x_2x_3=y_1y_2y_3$;

$\operatorname{R.H.S}=\displaystyle \frac{d_1d_2d_3x_1x_2x_3 D}{d_1d_2d_3}=x_1x_2x_3 D$.

To reach equality, I have to prove $D=d_1d_2d_3$

I tried to define: 
$a=d_1x_1$, $b=d_1y_1$;
$b=d_2x_2$, $c=d_2y_2$;
$c=d_3x_3$, $c=d_3y_3$.

then $\operatorname{L.H.S}=d_1d_2d_3x_1x_2x_3=d_1d_2d_3y_1y_2y_3$ $\implies$ $x_1x_2x_3=y_1y_2y_3$;

$\operatorname{R.H.S}=\displaystyle \frac{d_1d_2d_3x_1x_2x_3 D}{d_1d_2d_3}=x_1x_2x_3 D$.

To reach equality, I have to prove $D=d_1d_2d_3$

I tried to define: 
$a=d_1x_1$, $b=d_1y_1$;
$b=d_2x_2$, $c=d_2y_2$;
$c=d_3x_3$, $a=d_3y_3$.

then $\operatorname{L.H.S}=d_1d_2d_3x_1x_2x_3=d_1d_2d_3y_1y_2y_3$ $\implies$ $x_1x_2x_3=y_1y_2y_3$;

$\operatorname{R.H.S}=\displaystyle \frac{d_1d_2d_3x_1x_2x_3 D}{d_1d_2d_3}=x_1x_2x_3 D$.

To reach equality, I have to prove $D=d_1d_2d_3$, but I have no idea how to finish that.

Comment: You have to be screwing up a step somewhere, there's no way that $D = d_1d_2d_3$; just consider the case where $a = b = c > 1$.

Comment: If by L.H.S. you mean $L$, the lcm of $a$, $b$, and $c$, then the error is in writing $L.H.S.=d_1d_2d_3x_1x_2x_3$, because $d_1d_2d_3x_1x_2x_3=(d_1x_1)(d_2x_2)(d_3x_3)=abc$, not lcm$(a,b,c)$.

Comment: Also, there is a minor typo in the lines where you write $c=d_3y_3$.  I'm pretty sure those should all be $a=d_3y_3$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks for pointing out!